# PHP Error "Creating default object from empty value": How can this happen here?

Tags: php, reference

```
class Registry {
  public $reg = null;

  static function _access(&$obj, &$accessor = null) {
    if ($obj === null || !is_a($obj, __CLASS__)) {
      $obj = new Registry();
    }
    $accessor = $obj->reg;
    $obj->reg = &$accessor; /* -- error here -- */
  }
}

$reg = null;  
$obj = &$reg;
$acc = null;
for ($i=0; $i<3;++$i) {
  Registry::_access($obj, $acc);
  $obj = &$acc;
}
var_dump($reg);
```

I tried to boil down my code to this example function, here is what it should do:
It takes an object and an accessor.
If the object is null or not an obj of class Registry, it should make it one.
Then it should let the accessor have the value of the reg field and make it point to it.

In the for-loor loop, I do this 3 times, setting the next obj to the previous accessor. So the expected data-structure in the end is:

Registry $obj has a field $reg that is a Registry with a field $reg that is a Registry with a field $reg that is null. Probably its one more but you get the point.

However, I get this error:
" Creating default object from empty value in … ", pointing to the marked line.

What is happening there and how can I do this…?

**Supplement:**

Before the line with the error, $obj is an object of class Registry, so it has a field $reg. It should not be possible that it is a "default object". So: how can this happen?

**Expected results**

0th loop: $obj = null

1st loop: $obj = Registry with $reg = null

2nd loop: $obj = Registry with $reg = Registry with $reg = null

etc.

Comment: 1. Objects passed by reference. No need for the ampersands at parameters.
2. Change to `static function _access($obj, &$accessor = null)` and the code will run without error.

Comment: @MarkusZeller doesnt work, i dont get the expected struct. I need to pass by ref, because obj might be null, or a string, or an integer. If obj is an integer, it should be a Registry afterwards.

Comment: I don't get the purpose of what you are trying to do. This will end up in unmaintable code and anti-pattern. Why don't you return the object instead of juggling with references?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Running the code in current PHP versions (as in: PHP 8.2 or PHP 8.1) does not yield that error message.

Comment: @NicoHaase: the provider has PHP 7.4.33. I try to understand this problem to resolve it. I dont know why this error occures in that line. On my behalf, it should work.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Please explain where you see an "anti-pattern".

Comment: @rhavin A registry implements Singleton which also is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @MarkusZeller where do you see a singleton here…?

Comment: @rhavin The way you use the `_access()` method. Call it opinion based if you like :)

Comment: @MarkusZeller This is an EXAMPLE that boils down what is happening and I wanna know why it is happening.

Comment: Did you try to use xdebug? Then you can exactly see what variable hold which value and trace through every step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that regardless of how you declare a function, if you use an ampersand (`function foo(&$obj)`) or dont use it `function foo($obj)` on an object, you will always get an "unset-on-reference"-reference to the object. So, you can change the value of a reference inside a function, but not what the reference is referencing:

```
$a = 'test1';
$b = &$a;  // b is linked to the value of a
foo($b);

function foo(&$obj) {
   // $obj is linked to the value of a
   $obj = &$whatever; // $obj is now a link to $whatever,
   // but outside $b has NOT changed accordingly.
}
```

The only way I have found to circumvent this is by either return-by-reference (`function &foo()`) – but then you can only return one value – or by using a wrapper:

```
class Wrapper {
   public $pt = null;
}

class Test {
  public $test1 = 'test1';
  public $test2 = 'test2';
  // wont work, you cant change the reference inside
  // just its value.
  public function set(&$obj, $num) {
    if ($num == 1) {
      $obj = $this->test1;
      $this->test1 = &$obj;
      $obj = &$this->test2; // nope
    } else {
      $obj = $this->test2;
      $this->test1 = &$obj;
      $obj = &$this->test2; // nope
    }
  }
  // same, but with wrapper
  public function setW($obj, $num) {
    if ($num == 1) {
      $obj->pt = &$this->test1;
    } else {
      $obj->pt = &$this->test2;
    }
  }
}

$T = new Test();
$k = 'test0';
$T->set($k,1);
echo $k."<br>"; // test1
$T->set($k,2);
echo $k."<br>"; // test2
$T->test2 = 'changed2';
echo $k."<br>"; // still test2 :-(
echo "<br>Test with wrapper<br>";
$T = new Test();
$k = new Wrapper();
$k->pt = 'test0';
$T->setW($k,1);
echo $k->pt."<br>"; // test1
$T->setW($k,2);
echo $k->pt."<br>";  // test2
$T->test2 = 'changed2';
echo $k->pt."<br>"; // changed2
```